# How to fix large and ugly icons in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, icons

Icons of Explorer and Office programs are enlarged in an ugly way - pixelated and then blurred. See screenshot below (click for a larger version):

[image: Ugly icons in Word]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would not click on the first link.

Comment: Is this a laptop? Maybe your resolution is wrong? Have you tried with other resolutions?

Comment: It seems be to the first link is removed and a moderator has completely rewritten my post.
Yes, it is a laptop. No, I've test all possible resolutions, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Correction: No, I've tested all possible resolutions, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Did you change the DPI settings?

Comment: No, I haven't changed it.

Comment: @MohsenFarjami FYI, I'm not a moderator. But [it's common here on SuperUser for others to edit your posts](http://superuser.com/help/editing), in order to correct mistakes, improve legibility, add/remove tags, or do things for which you don't have the necessary privileges yet (like embedding images). If you think I made a mistake with my edit, please feel free to correct it.

Comment: No, thanks Mr. Indrek; by removing the first link, You've just made it better and decreased the fear that people like Firee would feel too, But I was shocked by such a big change in my post. I think some people are too cautious about security. I know people that even if they have an updated antivirus, would avoid connecting a flash drive to their computer.

I finally fixed the problem myself:
It is a common way to fix problems by restarting windows, refreshing, uninstalling and installing again and so on. here, by increasing DPI to 125% and decreasing it to 100%, the problem got solved.

Comment: @MohsenFarjami Glad to hear you solved your problem. You should post the solution as an answer, for the benefit of others who might have the same problem and find this post. Note that you may have to wait a little until the system lets you answer your own question. [See here for more information](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from comments:

> I finally fixed the problem myself: It is a common way to fix problems
>   by restarting windows, refreshing, uninstalling and installing again
>   and so on. here, by increasing DPI to 125% and decreasing it to 100%,
>   the problem got solved.

New:
at least once it appeared again and I fixed it, but I am not sure how to prevent it from occurring again.